# I need a regular expression extractor for input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-706-nKdYAVmSstJPgESlEikIJRgdfLz9ui-cas01.mts.org" /> <input

Tags: jmeter

Expression :

```
input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-706-nKdYAVmSstJPgESlEikIJRgdfLz9ui-
cas01.mts.org" /> <input
```

Please provide a regular expression for this for validation

i have tried with the below but not getting result

```
input type="hidden" name="lt" value="(.+?)-cas01.mts.org"
input type="hidden" name="lt" value="(.+?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), there are no pros and the cons are:

- Regular Expressions for HTML are hard to develop and maintain
- They are sensitive to markup change
- A slight amendment of [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) like attribute order change or if the input string will be split into 2 or more lines will run your regular expression

Consider using [CSS Selector](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, the relevant configuration is as simple as:

- CSS Selector Expression: `input[name=lt]`
- Attribute: `value`

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.It worked for me .